# What is the quickest Mac OS X app to use to remove the background of an image to make it transparent?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, utilities, image-editing

I followed the instructions in [How to use Preview for Basic Image Editing: Remove Backgrounds and Extract Shapes](http://www.ehow.com/how_2127316_using-preview-mac-osx-leopard.html) to use the Preview app to remove backgrounds with an image. The problem is that the "Instant Alpha" tool sometimes does not capture all the pixels and can't figure out how to use the rectangle tool to remove those remaining pixels. I tried highlighting the pixels and then pressing delete but it doesn't work. Can someone explain how to do it or recommend another free, lightweight Mac OS X tool to remove background to make it transparent? I do not want to use Photoshop or anything else expensive.

Comment: If someone knows how to do this quickly in Preview, I would prefer that. Thanks.

Comment: "I tried highlighting the pixels and then pressing delete" you gotta press backspace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said "free," but you also mentioned "nothing expensive like Photoshop"; there are solutions to your problem that do cost something but are nowhere nearly as expensive as Photoshop.

[Pixelmator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixelmator/id407963104?mt=12) is great for certain kinds of quick image editing. It's only $30 right now, though that will probably go up when the next major release finally comes out; I believe it's normally $60.

There's also [Acorn](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/acorn-the-image-editor-for/id402280036?mt=12), which is very similar and perhaps a hair's breadth easier to use, though since they've already had their first post-App Store major version release, it's more expensive at the moment ($50).

If it absolutely must be freeware, do have a look at Seashore, mentioned in a comment by Ian C.

Answer (score 5):

Just selecting an area and hitting delete just as you do with the Alpha tool should do it fine.  I tend to get a good outline with the alpha tool, then zoom in and use the lasso selection tool to draw around any stray pixels - remember to complete the lasso yourself, or it may complete it for you and if the end is not near the start, it will just draw a big line between the 2 across whatever is in its way.

You don't say what OS you are using, but I've done it this way in every OS since Tiger...

Comment: Since the OP prefers a Preview solution +1.

Answer (score 3):

The best simple image editor is [Seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/The_Seashore_Project/About.html). It's an open-source Cocoa app built around GIMP's technology. That means it provides advanced photo editing capabilities for free and does it in a simple-to-install native app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GIMP, which is free, but it runs in X11, which you will have to download separately. The GIMP has tools that are similar to Photoshop's tools.

Comment: [Seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/The_Seashore_Project/About.html) is a Cocoa port of GIMP. Runs native in OS X and behaves like an OS X app. Not running the most recent GIMP engine and not as many features as GIMP, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: good call, I have tried a few "nativized" gimp versions in the past and was always disappointed (at least after they broke and were no longer supported). i assume that would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create Your Own Transparent Image Files With Preview

Basically using Instant Alpha button, select the area you want to make it transparent, then delete the selection, then it will be done.

Just see the link below.

http://www.cultofmac.com/216093/create-your-own-transparent-image-files-with-preview-os-x-tips/

Answer (score 0):

The best app for Mac OS X to use to remove the background of an image is [BackgroundEraser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/background-eraser/id820985246?mt=12) (only $1.99). You can remove quickly any background.

There's also a [video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kjcVAFNVmw).

Answer (score 0):

It can be complicated. Go to [Super PhotoCut](http://www.effectmatrix.com/mac-appstore/free-remove-background-from-image-for-mac.htm) in the App Store. It is really super to instantly remove background from photo within a few seconds. I used it a lot which saved me much time.

[image: instant remove photo background]

Answer (score 0):

macOS now offers a built-in feature for background removal. It performs optimally when dealing with high quality, well-defined and contrast-rich images ; Simply right-click on the image you intend to remove the background from, navigate to ***Quick Action*** and click on ***Remove background***

[image: macOS screenshot that indicates where to click to trigger the background removal built-in feature]

Here's an example and its result

[image: Stock image to illustrate the background removal macOS feature]

[image: Stock image with the background removed]